# Grab label name of particular field

Tags: jquery, html

I can't figure out how to get label name for a particular field in this jquery code

I using the code below to place field values in a text area box.  I want grab the label name for that field.
Right now it is grabing the **name** of the field which is a number and that number is required,

**my html is structure this way -**

```
<fieldset id="section-106"><legend class='sectiontitle'>Project Overview</legend><table width='90%' border='0' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'><tr class="tr-106-608 tr-106" id="field-608"><td width='30%' valign='top' align='left' class="td-106-608 td-106 labeltext" id="td-field-608">Request Name :</td><td width='70%' align='left' class="td-106-608 td-106 td-106-608-label-name_Request Name labeltext" id="td-field-608"><table border='0' style='table-layout:auto'><tr><td id="td_2-field-608"><input id="608" name="608" maxlength="150" size="40" class="valuetext" value="" 0="" ></td><td valign='top'></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr class="tr-106-609 tr-106" id="field-609">
```

Is there a way to grab the label name from within the html structure above and to include in the jQuery below?

**my jquery is this:**

```
function combineFields(event) {
        $('#7470').val('');
        $("#6974,#1782, #1783").each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() != '') {
               var val = $(this).attr('name')+':  '+$(this).val();
               var mytextareaFld = $('#7470');
              mytextareaFld.val(mytextareaFld.val() + val + '\n');
            }

        })
} 
$("#6974,#1782, #1783").blur(combineFields);
```

Comment: fyi, IDs are not supposed to start with a number

Comment: @ThiefMaster In HTML 4, that's true. HTML5 is more lenient, and most browsers ignored that restriction for HTML 4 anyway. That said, it's still a bad idea because pure-number IDs aren't semantic -- they don't communicate what the element *represents* to other developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found away around this - for those in a similar situation.  I used the "alt" attribute, applied the label name to this attribute, added it to the code, so this gave the field another "name" that I could use as a reference.